# Android Studio 3.1.2 Gradle Error : Could not resolve all files for configuration ':lintClassPath'

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-studio-3.0, android-instant-run

I am on mac, using android studio 3.1.2 . I have changed the gradle version to 4.4 and Android plugin to 3.1.2
I have already changed the **compile** keyword to **implementation**  in the build.gradle

I am getting this error :

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':lint'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':lintClassPath'.
   > Could not find com.android.tools:sdk-common:26.1.2.
     Searched in the following locations:
         file:/Users/rp/Library/Android/sdk/extras/m2repository/com/android/tools/sdk-common/26.1.2/sdk-common-26.1.2.pom
         file:/Users/rp/Library/Android/sdk/extras/m2repository/com/android/tools/sdk-common/26.1.2/sdk-common-26.1.2.jar
```

how can this be fixed?

Comment: did you find a workaround for this?

Comment: Yes, changed the target sdk version to 26.

Comment: It worked in my case. thanks

Comment: By changing the sdk version?

Comment: Yes changing it from 27 to 26

Comment: And changed back to 27 and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

The cause of this issue is that Gradle can't find the Android SDK. There are several ways to fix it:

1. Define the ANDROID_HOME environment variable

   `ANDROID_HOME=your/path/to/android/sdk; export ANDROID_HOME`

or Add sdk.dir to the file local.properties, for example on my Linux computer

`sdk.dir=/home/sdeng/Android/Sdk`

2. if you already defined ANDROID_HOME or sdk.dir, it still happens. It probably something is wrong with the specific version of your Android SDK or Gradle daemon. Try to kill all Gradle processes, re-download the specific version of Android SDK.

   Or you can check the SDK at `$ANDROID_HOME/platforms/android-28`, where 28 is the compileSdkVersion defined in build.gradle
   Like other comment says, change to a good SDK version works in this case.